# Custom Validation in Repeater Control using asp.net

Tags: asp.net, validation, repeater

I am having text box, label and button in a repeater control. Button should validate the text box. If the user enter greater than number 4, error message should appear and the text box value should be change based on the label box value.

How to validate the textbox using custom validation inside repeater?

Answer (score 0):

On OnItemDataBound event OR OnItemCreated  event execute this code

```
            Label lbl = (Label)e.Item.FindControl("lblId"); 
            Button btn = (Button)e.Item.FindControl("btnId");
            TextBox txt = (TextBox)e.Item.FindControl("txtId");
            CustomValidator cfv = (CustomValidator)e.Item.FindControl("cfvId");
            if (cfv != null && txt!=null&&btn!=null&&lblId!=null)
            {
                cfv.ControlToValidate = txt.ClientID;
                cfv.ClientValidationFunction = "YourFunction";
                cfv.ValidationGroup = cfv.ClientID + "ValidationGroup";
                btn.ValidationGroup = cfv.ClientID + "ValidationGroup";
                lbl.AssociatedControlID=txt.ClientID;
            }

  //javascript code on client side
  function YourFunction(sender, args)
  {
      args.IsValid=parseInt(args.Value)<=4;
      if(!args.IsValid)
         $('#'+sender.controltovalidate).val($('label:[for="'+sender.controltovalidate+'"]').text());
      return;
  }
```

Comment: And next action  depends from what do you use clear javascript or jquery

Comment: With javascript or jquery? Do you define  AssociatedControlID property for your label? Can you show aspx code of your template?